# Converting binary data/numbers into a memorable format

Tags: formatting

What are my options for converting arbitrary binary data into a memorable format?

Are there any widely used standards? What is the most efficient way to do this? I.e. to encode the most data in the easiest-to-remember way?

Comment: Although I have answered this question, I am hoping other people will post alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitcoin's [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) standard, whereby numbers are split into 11 bits and each is mapped to a word from a list of 2048 words. These words are chosen whereby similar words are avoided and a word can be unambiguously determined based on the first 4 letters.